# Selecting list item and then input to php sql

Tags: php

I want to display list of items and on click of any of that list item it should go to php SQL query as search criteria.  I don't want to use select options and submit button.

Do I have to use java script and how or is there any other way.

I am able to pass value to next page using session variable but in this case I want to keep PHP SQL and HTML code on same page so that call is easy.

Comment: you could just make your list of items hyperlinks, and just add a param - ie. `yourPage.php?search=search1`, `yourPage.php?search=search2`, ...

Comment: You can use jQuery for that.

Comment: in PHP what syntax should I use to fetch that search value then?

Comment: if [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605243/selecting-list-item-and-then-input-to-php-sql#comment56956315_34605243) was for me, then you would use `$_GET`, ie. `if(isset($_GET['search'])) $search_value = $_GET['search']; // use $search_value to do your search.`

Comment: Sean- thanks a lot. without using Jquery and Ajax I was able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  jQuery Onclick event and pass the list values through ajax to PHP Sever page. In the same page you can show the Ajax Response(Search results) in the div.
example

```
<span onclick="getSearchResults(id)">list1</span>
<span onclick="getSearchResults(id)">list2</span>
<span onclick="getSearchResults(id)">list3</span>
```

Call Jquery Ajax dunction

```
function getSearchResults(id)
{
//jquery ajax code 
//show the response to search results div
}
```

Comment: This should be posted as comment. Otherwise add some codes here